# Can I add static extension fun for third-party class in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Given a third party class `ThirdClass`, which doesn't have a companion object, how can I define a static extension function for it? Something like this:

```
fun ThirdClass.Companion.hello(){}
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't extend objects that don't have a `companion` object (yet).

Comment: What problem are you solving? Please show some use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at the moment, but it's tracked under [KT-11968: Adding statically accessible members to an existing Java class via extensions](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11968) (despite the name, the discussion covers Kotlin classes/interfaces without a companion as well). See particularly the comments starting [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11968#focus=Comments-27-4355876.0-0).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to declare an object inside the class marked as companion like from this [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects).

```
class MyClass {
    companion object Factory {
        fun create(): MyClass = MyClass()
    }
}
```

Members of the companion object can be called by using simply the class name as the qualifier:

```
val instance = MyClass.create()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a static function from outside of the class definition, but you can make an extension function that will work on all instances:

```
fun ThirdClass.hello() = println("Hello from ${this.javaClass.name}!")

fun main() {
    ThirdClass().hello()
}
```

Output:

```
Hello from ThirdClass!
```